# Get top ten elements from Collection and save it in another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've wrote a cloud-function to order my collection by a field and then store the first 10 in a different collection. This is my approach so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {

  return admin.firestore().collection("myCollection")
    .orderBy("specificField", "desc")
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {

       //here: store the 10 elements in a different collection

      } else {
       // do nothing
        return null;
      }
    });

});
```

I don't know how to handle the querySnapshot. Is there anyone who can explain what I have to in the "here" part in the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest at least making an attempt, then showing what you tried that didn't work the way you expect.  There is plenty of documentation on how to write documents in Firestore.  Stack Overflow is not a free code generator.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am sorry if you feel like I use SO as a code generator. I made many attempts but no one seemed to work. I thought it's better to show my approach so far cause I feel like it's not that difficult. I just don't know how to handle the querySnapshot and thats the question, I have not even asekd for a code or something like that, but for a explanation. Isn't that what SO stands for?

Comment: Start with the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query

Comment: I know the documentation but still thanks...I try another approach maybe this one works. If not I am coming back :D thank you for your time.

Comment: When you do come back, can you clarify what you're asking? Are you literally asking how to write data to Firebase as covered in the documentation? Or are you asking how to get data from a Snapshot or... what specifically is the question?